# Задачка по Unity

Tags: unity3d

Есть коллекция

```
public List<GameObject> gameInvHeroCard = new List<GameObject>(5);
```

С нее создаются объекты на сцене

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // лимит карт
        {
            int x = -1;
            x = x + (i * 2);
            Instantiate(gameInvHeroCard[i], new Vector3(x, 15, -7), gameInvHeroCard[i].transform.rotation);

    }
```

Задача. При клике по объекту узнать номер индекса в Листе с которого он создался и записать в переменную, которая находиться на этом созданном объекте. То есть другой скрипт   (класс), который прикреплен к объекту.

Comment: добавьте поле к объекту и запишите туда индекс, сразу после инициализации

Comment: class one
{
    public int option=5;
}
 
class two
{ 
   one Newone;  //создаем поле класса
   public two() // конструктор
{
    Newone = new one; //создаем экземпляр класс
}
  int twoClass =  Newone.option; //присваиваем значение первого класса второму
 
}

Comment: Типа такого огорода городить)

Comment: Можете на примере показать

Comment: могу, но с компа, а сейчас я не у него :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<GameObject> temp = new list ......
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // лимит карт { int x = -1; x = x + (i * 2); temp.add(Instantiate(gameInvHeroCard[i], new Vector3(x, 15, -7), gameInvHeroCard[i].transform.rotation)); }
"Ваш лист = temp"
```

Таким образом все объекты будут иметь ссылку а не будут являться клонами , 
Если нужен пррсто индекс можно указывать в названии объекта

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // лимит карт { int x = -1; x = x + (i * 2); (Instantiate(gameInvHeroCard[i], new Vector3(x, 15, -7), gameInvHeroCard[i].transform.rotation)).name=""+i; }
```

В последствии просто просить с названия